# retrieve contact's nickname

Tags: android, contacts

I want to get the nickname of a contact from addressbook. I start with his phone number, query it and want the nickname (aka alias) as a result.

```
Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " = " + incomingNumber, null, null);

        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            Log.e("saymyname", cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Nickname.NAME)));
            Log.e("saymyname", cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Nickname.LABEL)));
        }
```

Output of the logs is the incomingNumber (first Log.e() ) and null (second Log.e() ), but I want to get the contact's nickname!

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nickname is held in a different table than the phone numbers, you have to query `ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI`

Check my answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044545/get-contact-info-from-android-contact-picker/3044835#3044835)

Answer (score 3):

The [answer from Pentium10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3054083/194894) was very helpful! Thanks!

If anybody needs a sample, look at the following code:

```
public String accessContact(String incomingNumber) {
        if (incomingNumber == null || "".equals(incomingNumber)) {
            return "unknown";
        }

        try {
            Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, new String[] {Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.TYPE, Phone.CONTACT_ID}, Phone.NUMBER + " = " + incomingNumber, null, null);

            int nameIndex = cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
            int typeIndex = cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE);
            int idIndex = cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID);

            String name;
            String type;
            String id;

            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                name = cur.getString(nameIndex);
                type = cur.getString(typeIndex);
                id = cur.getString(idIndex);
            } else {
                return "unknown";
            }

            cur = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, new String[] {ContactsContract.Data.DATA1}, ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);

            int nicknameIndex = cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1);
            String nickname;

            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                nickname = cur.getString(nicknameIndex);
                if (nickname.equals(incomingNumber)) {
                    return name;
                }
                return nickname;
            } else {
                return name;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "unknown";
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

(I don't have necessary reputation to comment so I have to add answer)

[TomTasche's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3059826/2897839) is misleading and it got me to waste a lot of time trying to figure out why I couldn't get the proper nickname on a contact I knew had one.

I found the answer by myself but got the confirmation from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6570030/2897839) that I was now doing it properly.

Basically when you read the [ContactsContract.Data](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html) documentation you read:

> Each row of the data table is typically used to store **a single piece** of contact information (such as a phone number) and its associated metadata (such as whether it is a work or home number).

That explains the shady part of TomTasche's code :

```
if (nickname.equals(incomingNumber)) {
                return name;
            }
```

Since doing a search with just the CONTACT_ID can return multiple rows (one for each information type), it's not guaranteed that the first one contains the nickname. When there is a nickname it will be in DATA1, but the [phone number](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html) is also found in DATA1.

The example part in the documentation of [ContactsContract.Data](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html) makes it clear that rows must be selected based on their MIME_TYPE, only when the MIME_TYPE is selected, can we start making sense of the content in the row itself.

A proper query would therefore be:

```
cursor =  getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{Nickname.NAME},
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "= ?",
                new String[]{contactID, Nickname.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},
                null);
```

(where Nickname is [ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Nickname](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Nickname.html))

I felt I had to say something on this topic to prevent other people wasting as much time as I did based on this sole topic (first one I found with my Google friend).

Comment: maybe the contact database changed, or I was just wrong back then (this answer is really old). Anyway, thanks for posting a better solution!

Comment: No problem. Knowledge is an incremental process anyway so I'm glad I could bring your answer up to date. Thanks for posting it in the first place :p