# resolve mail-address to contact's name

Tags: android, contacts

Assuming I have a contact saved in my addressbook, called "TomTasche" with the mail-address "stackoverflow@gmail.com". How can I retrieve the contact's name, if I only know the mail-address?

I already asked a similar questions about retrieving contact's nickname [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053554/retrieve-contacts-nickname), but if I change that code to query the mail, like that:

```
Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(Email.CONTENT_URI, new String[] {Email.DISPLAY_NAME, Email.TYPE, Email.CONTACT_ID}, Email.DATA + " = " + "stackoverflow@gmail.com", null, null);

final int nameIndex = cur.getColumnIndex(Email.DISPLAY_NAME);
final int typeIndex = cur.getColumnIndex(Email.TYPE);
final int idIndex = cur.getColumnIndex(Email.CONTACT_ID);

if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
    name = cur.getString(nameIndex);
    type = cur.getString(typeIndex);
    id = cur.getString(idIndex);
} else {
    name = UNKNOWN;
}
```

it forces close and logcat tells me that there's a syntax error near @gmail.

```
06-22 09:21:14.260: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(110): Writing exception to parcel
06-22 09:21:14.260: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(110): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "@gmail": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT display_name, data2, contact_id FROM view_data_restricted data WHERE (1 AND mimetype = 'vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2') AND (data1 = "Tom" <stackoverflow@gmail.com>)
```

Interesting is that it seems to query fine. Logcat prints out the contact's name:

```
06-22 09:21:14.260: [...] AND (data1 = "Tom" <stackoverflow@gmail.com>)
```

So, how am I able to retrieve the name?

Thanks

Tom

**edit:**

Syntax Error is caused by missing quotes, **but cursor returns null anyway.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Phone.DISPLAY_NAME` instead of `Email.DISPLAY_NAME` in both `query()` and `getColumnIndex()` (first 2 lines).

**edit:**

There's also special uri for e-mail lookups: `Email.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI`.
It seems to be more convenient in use (no need to put quotas or manually compose selection argument as in your code):

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Email.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, Uri.encode("stackoverflow@gmail.com"));
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{Email.CONTACT_ID, mail.DISPLAY_NAME, Email.TYPE, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Plus 1 for pointing out that Phone.DISPLAY_NAME works whereas Email.DISPLAY_NAME doesn't.