# android getting a contacts nickname

Tags: android, android-widget, contacts

Anyone have any luck querying for a contacts nickname given a phone number or contacts name?

Thanks

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Nickname.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a view on this question: [retrieve contact's nickname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053554/retrieve-contacts-nickname/3054083#3054083).

And also this question: [get contact info from android contact picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044545/get-contact-info-from-android-contact-picker/3044835#3044835)

Comment: I am not sure how I couldnt find those links, but they did help. The first one has a utility method that did not work, but after some fiddling and combining the results of both links, I was able to do it. Thanks a bunch.