# retrieve contact's nickname, part 2

Tags: android, contacts

A few weeks ago I asked exactly the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053554/retrieve-contacts-nickname). At first, I thought the answers solved my problem, but they didn't. I just didn't notice that I wasn't able to solve my problem with those answers.

However, what I've got now is:

```
final Cursor phoneCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode("'" + incomingNumber + "'")), null, null, null, null);
phoneCursor.moveToFirst();

String lookupString = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.LOOKUP_KEY));

final Cursor dataCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.Data.LOOKUP_KEY + "=" + "'" + lookupString + "'", null, null);
dataCursor.moveToFirst();

Log.e("smn", "display_name: " + dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME)));
Log.e("smn", "nickname: " + dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1)));
```

Output looks like this:

```
08-14 17:41:02.106: ERROR/smn(20146): display_name: Tom Tasche
08-14 17:41:02.106: ERROR/smn(20146): nickname: null
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053554/retrieve-contacts-nickname/3054083#3054083) told me that Nicknames are held in Data-table, but although I'm querying Data-table, I don't retrieve the contact's alias saved in my addressbook.

[image: contact with alias]

I already tried it the other way: I inserted a new alias for this contact. And that worked fine. So, nicknames seem to work.
Additionally, I've printed out every field that's saved in Data-table, again, without no luck.

Any ideas? Maybe I'm doing something completely wrong, but at the moment I don't see what's the problem...

Thanks for your help

Tom

Comment: Does your phone runs with Sense UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a "workaround":

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookup);
InputStream stream = settings.context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

int length = stream.available();
if (length <= 0) {
    return;
}

byte[] vcard = new byte[length];
int bytesRead = stream.read(vcard, 0, length);
if (bytesRead < length) {
    return;
}

String vcardString = new String(vcard, 0, bytesRead, "UTF-8");

String SPLIT = "X-ANDROID-CUSTOM:vnd.android.cursor.item/nickname;";
if (vcardString.contains(SPLIT)) {
    vcardString = vcardString.substring(vcardString.indexOf(SPLIT) + SPLIT.length());
    vcardString = vcardString.substring(0, vcardString.indexOf(';'));

    name = vcardString;
}
```

It's really stupid, but it works and it's not that slow (~300 milliseconds).

Good luck

Tom