# Fetch Contacts in android application

Tags: android, android-contacts

I was following these links to get the contacts in my application

[How to call Android contacts list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866769/how-to-call-android-contacts-list)

http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/

I can display the list of contacts on phone but

-

1. I want to add a checkbox at each contact so that user can select
   multiple contacts and by clicking the done button he should be able 
   to get all the
          contacts he selected
2. Also I want to get the name of contact as well as the phone
          number of contact , see my code :

```
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri contactData = data.getData();
                    Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        String name = c.getString(c
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        String number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
                        Log.v("name", name +" "+number);
                        // TODO Whatever you want to do with the selected contact
                        // name.
                    }
                }
```

on log cat it shows output as :

```
01-09 12:46:41.688: V/name(699): Xyz 1
```

that is the name of contact is xyz and it has atleast 1 phone number associated with it.Please help me on how can i get the number associated with that contact.

**EDIT :**

if i use this(`String number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NUMBER));`) line in code the I get following exception :

```
01-09 13:33:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(786): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 13:33:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(786): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0r1-2C2E30/1 (has extras) }} to activity {sra.com/sra.com.ContactsDemo}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'number' does not exist
01-09 13:33:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3515)
01-09 13:33:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3557)
01-09 13:33:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-09 13:33:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2063)
01-09 13:33:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 13:33:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-09 13:33:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-09 13:33:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 13:33:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-09 13:33:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-09 13:33:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-09 13:33:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-09 13:33:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(786): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'number' does not exist
01-09 13:33:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:314)
01-09 13:33:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.database.CursorWrapper.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CursorWrapper.java:99)
01-09 13:33:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at sra.com.ContactsDemo.onActivityResult(ContactsDemo.java:49)
01-09 13:33:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3890)
01-09 13:33:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3511)
01-09 13:33:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: also see my this question and help me solve it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831310/android-contacts-on-listview

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By seeing the answers, I think you got the answer how to fetch contacts and now you want to get the selected contacts on your activity.

> To fetch contact number specific to the contact name:

```
ContentResolver contactResolver = getContentResolver(); 
Cursor cursor = contactResolver.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + "=?", new String[]{contactName}, null);

if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do {
       String number = cursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
    }while (cursor.moveToNext() ); 
}
```

**Note:** Here `contactName` is the contact name of which you want to fecth contact numbers.

> I am assuming that you have shown the contacts with checkbox in
>   ListView and here is your solution to get the contact list selected by
>   the user to your activity:

**1.** Start your contact activity with `startActivityForResult()`.

**2.** Initialize `ArrayList` variable in contact activity say it `contactArrayList`.

**3.** When user `checks the checkbox`, add this contact in your `contactArrayList` and keep on adding and when `unchecks` then remove the contact from the `contactArrayList`.

**4.** When user presses done then set the result ok with the selected contact list which you have added in `contactArrayList` like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putStringArrayList("contacts", contactArrayList);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

and `finish()` this activity.

**5.** On your calling activity override:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null ){
             Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
             bundle =  data.getExtras();
             ArrayList list = bundle.getStringArrayList("contacts");
    }
}
```

**Note:** The above code was tested over 2.3.3.

Answer (score 4):

Please try this code

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    String name, number = "";
    String id;
    c.moveToFirst();
    for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
        name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

        if (Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
            Cursor pCur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id },
                    null);
            while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                number = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            }
        }
        Log.i("name ", name + " ");
        Log.i("number ", number + " ");
        c.moveToNext();
```

Comment: by using this code segment i get all contacts but i want to get only the selected contact and show that contact's name and number on my list view..how can i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

In here you have got the cursor c

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Phones.CONTENT_URI, null, null,null, null);
```

to get the name

```
String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(People.NAME));
```

to get the number

```
String number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(People.NUMBER));
```

You can iterate through the cursor and save them to a list. Create a checkbox list view and bind with that list.

Comment: are you testing on emulator or on phone?

Comment: You need to have contacts in your contact list.

Comment: i have contacts on my contact list on both emulator as well as on phone it is behaving same

Comment: Please try this one.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044545/get-contact-info-from-android-contact-picker

Answer (score 2):

Simply, have a contact data object, and whenever you select any item in list, set value of that contact into this field.

in

```
AdapterView.onItemClickListener()
{
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView list, View view, int position, long id)
   {
      Contact contact=listContacts.get(position);
      selectedContact=contact;//If Done Button on List
      //if activity is to be finished on selection
      { 
         Intent intent=new Intent();
         intent.putExtra(KEY_NAME, contact.Name);
         ....
         setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
         finish();
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below:

```
ContentResolver contactResolver = getContentResolver();     
Cursor cursor = contactResolver.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + "=?", new String[]{contactName}, null);    
if(cursor.getCount() > 0){    
    cursor.moveToFirst();    
    do {    
       String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));    
    }while (cursor.moveToNext() );     
}
```