# Android Contacts on listview

Tags: android, listview, android-contacts

I want to add the selected contacts on a listview in my application .I am getting selected code using following code but it is not showing selected contacts on listview .Please help me with what and where I am doing wrong

```
public class Contacts extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Button AddNewContact;
private Button AddFrmContacts;
private ListView EmergencyContactList;
private final int PICK = 1001;
private final int NEW = 1002;
ArrayList<ContactDetails> ContactList = new ArrayList<ContactDetails>();
ContactDetails CD = new ContactDetails(null, null);
ContactsAdapter contactsAdapter = null;
String[] ContactsArray = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_contacts);
    EmergencyContactList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.emergency_contact_list);
    ContactsArray = new String[ContactList.size()]; 
    contactsAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(Contacts.this, R.layout.contacts_listitem,ContactsArray);
    EmergencyContactList.setAdapter(contactsAdapter);
    AddNewContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_new);
    AddFrmContacts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.from_contacts);

    EmergencyContactList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.v("Item position :",
                    EmergencyContactList.getSelectedItemPosition() + "");
        }
    });
    AddFrmContacts.setOnClickListener(this);
    AddNewContact.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.v("contactlist on resume :", ContactList.isEmpty() + " "
            + ContactList.size());
    if (!ContactList.isEmpty()) {
        Log.v("name on resume :", ContactList.get(0).Name);
        Log.v("name on resume :", ContactList.get(0).Number);
        ContactsArray = getContactsArray(ContactList);
        contactsAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(Contacts.this, R.layout.contacts_listitem,ContactsArray);
        contactsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        EmergencyContactList.setAdapter(contactsAdapter);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.add_new:
        Intent NewContactIntent = new Intent(Contacts.this,
                SOSAddNewContact.class);
        startActivityForResult(NewContactIntent, NEW);
        break;
    case R.id.from_contacts:
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        // calling OnActivityResult with intenet And Some conatct for
        // Identifie
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK);
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
    String name = null;
    String PhoneNumber = "";
    switch (reqCode) {
    case (PICK):
        Uri contactData = data.getData();
        Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            name = c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            Log.v("_ID", name);
            int HasNumber = c
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER);
            if (HasNumber > 0) {
                Uri result = data.getData();
                Log.v("TAG", "Got a contact result: " + result.toString());
                String id = result.getLastPathSegment();
                try {
                    c = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                            Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id },
                            null);
                    int contactnumberidx = c.getColumnIndex(Phone.DATA);
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        PhoneNumber = c.getString(contactnumberidx);
                        Log.v("TAG", "Got number: " + PhoneNumber);
                        CD = new ContactDetails(name, PhoneNumber);
                        ContactList.add(CD);
                    } else {
                        Log.w("TAG", "No results");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "Failed to get phone data", e);
                } finally {
                    if (c != null) {
                        c.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    case NEW :
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            Log.v("on activity result", "OK");
        else
            Log.v("result", "not OK");
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        if(extras != null){
        name = extras.getString("Name");
        PhoneNumber = extras.getString("Number");
        CD = new ContactDetails(name, PhoneNumber);
        ContactList.add(CD);
        for(int i = 0;i<ContactList.size();i++)
            Log.v("ContactList", i+" "+ContactList.get(i).Name);
        }else{
            Log.v("extras ", "NULL");
        }
        break;
    }
}

public String[] getContactsArray(ArrayList<ContactDetails> List){
    if(!List.isEmpty()){
        for(int i=0;i<=List.size()-1;i++){
            ContactsArray = new String[List.size()];
            ContactsArray[i] = List.get(i).Name +"\n"+ List.get(i).Number;
        }
    }
    return ContactsArray;
}
}
```

**LOGCAT**

```
01-16 17:23:50.954: I/InputReader(61): Device reconfigured: id=0x0, name=qwerty2, display size is now 320x480
01-16 17:23:50.954: I/InputManager-Callbacks(61): No virtual keys found for device qwerty2.
01-16 17:23:51.379: I/ARMAssembler(61): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00001004_00000000 [ 65 ipp] (85 ins) at [0x4437d520:0x4437d674] in 908313 ns
01-16 17:23:51.399: I/ARMAssembler(61): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001001_00000000 [ 91 ipp] (114 ins) at [0x4437d678:0x4437d840] in 707349 ns
01-16 17:23:52.950: I/ActivityManager(61): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.sos.emergency/.SOSAddContacts } from pid 386
01-16 17:23:53.080: V/contactlist on resume :(386): true 0
01-16 17:23:53.389: I/ActivityManager(61): Displayed com.sos.emergency/.Contacts: +415ms
01-16 17:23:54.040: I/ActivityManager(61): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.sos.emergency/.SOSAddNewContact } from pid 386
01-16 17:23:54.429: I/ActivityManager(61): Displayed com.sos.emergency/.SOSAddNewContact: +374ms
01-16 17:24:05.449: W/KeyCharacterMap(386): No keyboard for id 0
01-16 17:24:05.449: W/KeyCharacterMap(386): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
01-16 17:24:13.729: D/dalvikvm(61): GREF has increased to 401
01-16 17:24:24.400: V/intent data(386): abc 5555555555
01-16 17:24:24.450: V/on activity result(386): OK
01-16 17:24:24.450: V/ContactList(386): 0 abc
01-16 17:24:24.450: V/contactlist on resume :(386): false 1
01-16 17:24:24.459: V/name on resume :(386): abc
01-16 17:24:24.459: V/name on resume :(386): 5555555555
01-16 17:24:26.850: I/ActivityManager(61): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts cmp=com.android.contacts/.ContactsListActivity } from pid 386
01-16 17:24:27.230: D/dalvikvm(180): GC_CONCURRENT freed 482K, 49% free 3050K/5959K, external 716K/1038K, paused 4ms+5ms
01-16 17:24:27.400: I/ContactsListActivity(180): Called with action: android.intent.action.PICK
01-16 17:24:28.299: I/ActivityManager(61): Displayed com.android.contacts/.ContactsListActivity: +1s431ms
01-16 17:24:30.419: V/_ID(386): Jordan
01-16 17:24:30.419: V/TAG(386): Got a contact result: content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0r4-3F494F332D47/4
01-16 17:24:30.480: V/TAG(386): Got number: 845-435-3555
01-16 17:24:30.489: V/contactlist on resume :(386): false 2
01-16 17:24:30.489: V/name on resume :(386): abc
01-16 17:24:30.489: V/name on resume :(386): 5555555555
01-16 17:24:30.550: W/InputManagerService(61): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4050be88 (uid=10000 pid=180)
01-16 17:24:39.319: I/ActivityManager(61): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts cmp=com.android.contacts/.ContactsListActivity } from pid 386
01-16 17:24:39.360: I/ContactsListActivity(180): Called with action: android.intent.action.PICK
01-16 17:24:39.689: D/dalvikvm(180): GC_CONCURRENT freed 333K, 47% free 3238K/6023K, external 914K/1038K, paused 5ms+6ms
01-16 17:24:39.979: I/ActivityManager(61): Displayed com.android.contacts/.ContactsListActivity: +643ms
01-16 17:24:41.269: V/_ID(386): Akriti
01-16 17:24:41.269: V/TAG(386): Got a contact result: content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0r3-2D414F3D533D/3
01-16 17:24:41.309: V/TAG(386): Got number: 854-741-1111
01-16 17:24:41.319: V/contactlist on resume :(386): false 3
01-16 17:24:41.330: V/name on resume :(386): abc
01-16 17:24:41.330: V/name on resume :(386): 5555555555
01-16 17:24:41.389: W/InputManagerService(61): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4050be88 (uid=10000 pid=180)
01-16 17:25:00.189: D/dalvikvm(130): GC_CONCURRENT freed 246K, 48% free 2970K/5703K, external 956K/1038K, paused 5ms+6ms
```

Comment: Are you able to see the logged text in onActivityResult()? Does you ContactsList() contains the contacts you selected when activity resumes?

Comment: @Hiral : see my edit I have added logs too

Comment: can you show your ContactsAdapter? and yes,just declare ContactAdapter as ContactsAdapter contactsAdapter; instead of putting null there at initialization time.

Comment: @hiral : i have added code see now

Comment: Why dont you try using custom ArrayAdapter class instead of BaseAdapter?

Comment: @Hiral : now i have posted the new code in my question now i have used arraryadapter instead of baseadapter and still its not showing items on listview

Comment: are you getting any errors or so in logcat? please post your logcat too.so that i can see whether you are getting logged values or not?

Comment: @Hiral: see now i have posted logcat too

Comment: try logging ContactsArray's length just before you define adapter in onResume().

Comment: it is showing correct length there

Comment: remove the line contactsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 and see if it works.Also remove code for defining and setting your adapter to listview from onCreate().

Comment: You should then cut code of listview onItemClickListener's code from onCreate and paste it after you set your adapter to listview in onResume().

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6754/discussion-between-hiral-and-droidshruti)

Comment: please join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6754/discussion-between-hiral-and-droidshruti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making following changes to your current adapter class:

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<ContactDetails> contactDetails = new ArrayList<ContactDetails>();
    Context c;    
    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ContactsAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<ContactDetails> ContactDetails) {

        contactDetails = ContactDetails;        
        c=context;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);  
        Log.v("constructor", contactDetails.size()+"");
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        Log.v("getCount", "");
        return contactDetails.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        Log.v("getItem", position+" ");
        return contactDetails.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        Log.v("getItemId", position+"");
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        Log.v("in :","get View");        

        if (convertView == null)
        {            
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_listitem, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.text=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

            Log.v("TAG", "convert view not null");
        } 
        else       
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

        textview.setText(contactDetails.get(position).Name);

        return convertView;
    }
    static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView text;            
    }
}
```

and also include layout file named **contacts_listitem.xml** as shown below in my answer.

Now you need to change these lines in your main activity too:

```
...
contactsAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(Contacts.this,ContactList);
EmergencyContactList.setAdapter(contactsAdapter);
...
```

Here,also you have not set adapter to your listview so it is not showing you anything there.you missed the line **EmergencyContactList.setAdapter(contactsAdapter);**.
please do as above and let me know the result.

**EDIT** :

You can also try using custom ArrayAdapter class like:

**ContactsAdapter.class:**

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    String[] array;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ContactsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] objects)
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        array=objects;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);               
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {       
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView==null)
        {
                 convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_listitem, null);
                 holder = new ViewHolder();

                 holder.text=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                 convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
                holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

        holder.text.setText(array[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView text;            
    }
}
```

Create a layout file **contacts_listitem.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:textSize="18dip"
        android:padding="5dip"      
        android:textColor="#90000000"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now you need to use ContactsAdapter's object in your main activity like:

```
...
ContactsAdapter aa=new ContactsAdapter(context,R.layout.contacts_listitem, new String[]{"contact1","contact2","contact3","contacts4"});
listView.setAdapter(aa);
...
```

Here,you can build your String array in onActivityResult() accordingly.(I didn't get what you have done in your adapter class to show contact details so i just put strings from String array in adapter.You have to code as per your need.)

**EDIT :**

Change these lines of code in your app:

```
public String[] getContactsArray(ArrayList<ContactDetails> List)
{    
    ContactsArray = new String[List.size()];
    for(int i=0;i<=List.size()-1;i++)
    {           
        ContactsArray[i] = List.get(i).Name +"\n"+ List.get(i).Number;
    }   
    return ContactsArray;
}
```

Here,you don't need to check if the list is empty or not,because you already do so before calling this function.

Comment: Have you try setting adapter to listview to?you must set it..in your code,i didn't find it.

Comment: Thanks Hiral for your quick responses,Solved my problem :)