# How to make a phone call (to call a given person) if we know the contact's _ID

Tags: android

My problem is that I store the contacts/persons' _ID in a database and I want to initiate a phone call in order to call the stored contact when the user presses a button.

I retrieve the _ID from a Cursor and store it into a database

```
String CONT_ID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)); ...
```

Later on, when the user presses a button I call

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("content://contacts/people/" + CONT_ID));
 startActivity(intent);
```

Now the **problem is that the dialer is displayed but it is "empty", it does not display the desired person**.

So, it seems that it does not fill in the person. The Android development guide says at the Intent description:

ACTION_DIAL content://contacts/people/1 -- Display the phone dialer with the person filled in.

How else should I fill in the desired person? Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

> Uri.parse("content://contacts/people/" + CONT_ID)

Here you are expecting `content://contacts/people/ + CONT_ID` should give the phone number but it will not happen bcoz you need to query `content provider`.

**Note:** Please refer this link to fetch contacts:

[Fetch Contacts in android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785131/fetch-contacts-in-android-application)