# How to extract contacts from the android phone and store/import into application in the emulator?

Tags: android, import, android-emulator, store, contacts

How to extract contacts from android phone and store or import into an application to display the contacts?

Comment: check this..may be helpful for you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785131/fetch-contacts-in-android-application

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question does not conform to the expected format : stackoverflow.com/faq#questions . You should ask help to solve a real issue, not how to do something. Please, search by yourself and come back when you'll get stucked.

Answer (score 0):

Android stores contacts using content providers storage method. So that its data can be shared between different applications. This solution will help you - [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721279/how-to-read-contacts-on-android-2-0)