# How to obtain contact information from an Intent in Android?

Tags: android, cursor, android-contacts

I am using intent to display contact list. From contacts I want to get contact information like firstname, secondname, emailid, phonenumber. I want all the information in `onActivityForResult()` for selected contact.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);  
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been answered many times, please check these posts out:

[How to read contacts on Android 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721279/how-to-read-contacts-on-android-2-0)

[get contact info from android contact picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044545/get-contact-info-from-android-contact-picker)

[How to call Android contacts list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866769/how-to-call-android-contacts-list)

Google Android Developer Documentations:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderId, Bundle args) {
    /*
     * Appends the search string to the base URI. Always
     * encode search strings to ensure they're in proper
     * format.
     */
    Uri contentUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(mSearchString));

    return new CursorLoader(
        getActivity(),
        contentUri,
        PROJECTION,
        null,
        null,
        null
    );
}
```

Source:
http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html