# How to extract phone number from the selected contact?

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

```
public class ImportContactsActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button pickContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contacts);
    pickContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });
}

public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (reqCode) {
    case (1) :
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri contactData = data.getData();
        Cursor c =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
          String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NAME));
          TextView contactView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactView);
          contactView.setText(name.toString());
        }
      }
      break;
    }
}
```

I am developing an Android apps and I am importing the phone contacts into my apps, after user clicks on the selected contact, the contact will be shown in a TextView and the phone number will be stored in the sharedpreferences... May I know how to achieve it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?

```
Uri contactData = data.getData();
Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
      String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NAME));
      String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NUMBER));
      String email = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.PRIMARY_EMAIL_ID));
      contactName.setText(name);
      contactNumber.setText(number);
      contactEmail.setText(email);
```

For store in [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)..

```
  // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
  // All objects are from android.context.Context
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putString("phonenumber", number);

  // Commit the edits!
  editor.commit();
```

The above code is just for understanding..

Comment: Thanks for the info, do I need to add something in the manifest?

Comment: Yes, add permission.. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>

Comment: I follow ur reference, but when i click on one of the contacts, it force close my apps...

Comment: Likewise, I am thinking about opening up a new question in regards to this matter.

Answer (score 0):

A possible duplicate of the following link

[get contact info from android contact picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044545/get-contact-info-from-android-contact-picker)

Refer to the above link. It has been answered in detail.