# Can (and how) Android App read the GMAIL (email address) of the play store it was downloaded from?

Tags: android, android-permissions

Android 9 +

I was not sure if Account permission is the same as the email address.
I have the same app on 2 different phones, I want to understand if they have the same "Account" owner, can it be done ?

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9844686?hl=en

Comment: i'm not sure if you can see which email was used to download the app, but perhaps you could try use the `AccountManager` to see which accounts a user has something like -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22551459/how-to-check-whether-user-have-gmail-account

Comment: The account I get back, is it just a name/ id ?

Comment: And it level dangerous so the client need to approve it req, right ?